# "order two sequence" in a paper of Waldhausen

Tags: ct.category-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras

In F. Waldhausen's paper "Algebraic K-theory of generalized free products, Part I", page 142,line 19, there is a term "order two sequence". Can anyone explain its meaning to me? 
According to the context, it should be a generalization of short exact sequence. Thanks!

Comment: Dear @Kun Wang: I think it would be very helpful if you were to copy the relevant text from Waldhausen's article into the question. All other things being equal, a question which is clear and self-contained is always easier to answer.

Comment: Thanks! Here is a link to the article:http://pub.uni-bielefeld.de/luur/download?func=downloadFile&recordOId=1782174&fileOId=2313704

Answer (score 1):

An "order two sequence" is a sequence of morphisms such that the composition of any two consecutive morphisms is the zero morphism. At the point you are asking about in Waldhausen's paper, the condition is then $\kappa \circ \iota=0$ (which always holds by the definition of *completed splitting diagram*).

References:

[Barry Mitchell, Theory of Categories, Section 15]

[Marco Grandis, On the categorical foundation of homological and homotopical algebra, Section 1.2]